# Providers in angular modules

Tags: angular

I have this scenario. I have the following hierarchy:

- DataCrudQueryService extends to QueryService.
- QueryService extends to QuerBodyService.
- QuerBodyService extends to QueryInfoService.
- DataPivotService extends to QuerBodyService.

I need the "QueryService", "QueryBodyService" and "QueryInfoService" services to have a single instance and from the "DataCrudQueryService" and "DataPivotService" services the same information can be queried from both points.

I don't understand very well how I should create the providers of my module as I lack knowledge of the part of useValue, useClass, useExisting...

Please help!

Comment: Hi, For these services "QueryService", "QueryBodyService" and "QueryInfoService" you can use `useClass` and for these services "DataCrudQueryService" and "DataPivotService" you can use `useExisting`.

Comment: This also depends on whether you are talking about module providers and/or component providers. I suggest reading this blog post on the topic: https://dev.to/angular/a-practical-guide-to-providers-in-angular-3c96